# How to make a URL which has parameter values wrapped around a JSON Object for invoking an API?

Tags: php, android, json

I made a registration system which returns certain values and updates a database everytime a HTML form is submitted. Here is the code for **register.php**

```
<?php
require_once "include/functions.php";
$db = new functions;

//json response array
$response = array("error" => FALSE);

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST'){

    if(isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['password']) && isset($_POST['confirm_password']) && !empty($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['email'])
       && !empty($_POST['password']) && !empty($_POST['confirm_password'])){


        //receiving the POST parameters
        $name = $db->sanitizeString($_POST['name']);  //Sanitizing the string 
        $email = $db->sanitizeString($_POST['email']);
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $confirm_password = $_POST['confirm_password'];

        //check if password is equal to confirm_password to continue

        if($db->passwordsMatch($password, $confirm_password)){

        //check whether user exists with the same validated email
           if($db->userExist($email) && filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){

               //user exists already
               $response["error"]= TRUE;
               $response["error_msg"]= "User already exists with email". $email;
               echo json_encode($response);
           }
           else if(!($db->userExist($email)) && filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){

               //user does not exist
               $hash= bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(78));

               $user= $db-> storeUser($name, $email, $password, $hash);
               if($user){

                  //new user 
                  $response["error"]= FALSE;
                  $response["uid"]= $user["unique_id"];
                  $response["user"]["name"]= $user["name"];
                  $response["user"]["email"]= $user["email"];
                  $response["user"]["created_at"]= $user["created_at"];
                  $response["user"]["updated_at"]= $user["updated_at"];
                  $response["user"]["status"]= $user["status"];
                  echo json_encode($response);
                  $db->sendEmail($email, $hash);

               }
               else{

                  //user failed to store 
                  $response["error"]= TRUE;
                  $response["error_msg"]= "Unknown error occurred in registration";
                  echo json_encode($response);
               }                 
           }
           else{

              //email address is not valid
              $response["error"]= TRUE;
              $response["error_msg"]= "Invalid email address ".$email;
              echo json_encode($response);
           }
       }

       //password and confirm password do not match
       else{
          $response["error"]= TRUE;
          $response["error_msg"]= "Password and Confirm password mismatch";
          echo json_encode($response);
       }
   }

   //Some parameters may be missing in the form being submitted
   else{
      $response["error"]= TRUE;
      $response["error_msg"]= "Required parameters are missing";
      echo json_encode($response);
   }
}
?>
```

**functions.php** basically has all the helper functions needed for **register.php**.
Now I want to use this file which can be called from an Android device for registration. Now the person making the Android part asks me to provide a readymade url needed to invoke the API and he send me an example of an URL which has param values wrapped in a JSON Object.

Can someone please help me to understand what he is actually asking of me and what do I really need to provide.

**EDIT**

The example URL provided to me by the Android person is this

http://umbria4.prosperoware.com/Api/Account/PingrequestObject={"authentication":{"AppId":"c30605e1-4920-48ff-88d0-e5b95d9f9f27","password":"umbria","username":"alexey.marcus","useWindowsAuthentication":"false"}}

Comment: It seems that Android person want you to parse JSON object insted of usual `$_POST` variable

Comment: Can you provide the example url and json request?

Comment: please check my edit @DainisAbols

Comment: Kind of incorrect url. This is not GET nor POST variant. Assume that it should be like ?PingrequestObject={"authentication": ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your question => your php part should listen for 2 types of requests, Kind of:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST'){
  // your code here
} elseif( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'GET' ){
   try{
     $authentication =  json_decode($_GET['PingrequestObject']);
      if(isset($authentication->name) && isset($authentication->email) && isset($authentication->password) && // etc...) ){
        //  make your code here  
     }
   }catch(Exception $ex){
     echo $ex->getMessage();
   }

}
```

Comment: i tried your method and it is creating a problem, can you please check this question of mine http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37570184/no-response-from-php-script-when-calling-it-using-a-readymade-url-containing-jso

Comment: @CodeRabbit seems to me, that no. "page not found"

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that this is your URL (you won't get username and password via GET parameters!):

```
http://www.mywebsite/api/register.php
```

I think that you will get a JSON content as a body of a POST request.

Now you can simply parse JSON and get parameters out. Let's say that you will be provided with a JSON like:

```
{username: "Username", password:"some_kind_of_a_password"}
```

You can read the body of a POST request like this (it depends really on how the data is sent):

```
$inputJSON = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

Now, convert this JSON string to an associative array:

```
$registrationInput = json_decode( $inputJSON, TRUE );
```

So, you can acces fields now, as you could in any associative array:

```
$name = $registrationInput["username"];
$pass = $registrationInput["password"];
```

How this helps.

Answer (score 0):

When you receive a json data, you can just decode it and user the values to chekc in your form:

```
$json = '{"authentication":{
            "AppId":"c30605e1-4920-48ff-88d0-e5b95d9f9f27",
            "password":"umbria",
            "username":"alexey.marcus",
            "useWindowsAuthentication":"false"
            }
        }';


$data = json_decode($json);

var_dump( $data->authentication->AppId );
var_dump( $data->authentication->password );
var_dump( $data->authentication->username );
```

Now feed them into your script and check if they match

Comment: By the way, I hope those are not live data, meaning, the appid, username and password. Or pretty much everyone will know the access info now.

Comment: But how would you actually receive the json data from a URL ? @Dainis Abols